# Retrofit POST request response in JSON array

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit2

I'm beginner at this. I'm trying to get Response from POST request that in a JSONarray. And when i try to get response on the array, i can get the JSON object. this is my POJO

User.Java

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String user;

    @SerializedName("pass")
    @Expose
    private String pass;

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Datum> data;

    public User(String user, String pass, String mesaage){
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public ArrayList<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Datum.Java:

```
public class Datum {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("mk_nama")
    @Expose
    private String mkNama;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getMkNama() {
        return mkNama;
    }

    public void setMkNama(String mkNama) {
        this.mkNama = mkNama;
    }
}
```

this is my Interface

```
public interface UserClient {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
Call<User> loginAccount (
                            @Field("user") String username,
                            @Field("pass") String password
);}
```

and this is my MainActivity

```
private void sendNetworkRequest(String username, String password) {

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://prht.herokuapp.com/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    UserClient client = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
    Call<User> call = client.loginAccount(username,password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.body().getData(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "BAD ERROR" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I seem to can't reach the object of JSONarray in getData()

Comment: post your json response

Comment: the response suppose to be this
"data": [
    {
      "id": "90",
      "username": "10090",
      "mk_nama": "XXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  ]

Comment: is you problem is with only the arraylist. I mean are you getting data in other fields like `username`, `pass`, `status`

Comment: yes, it's only occur on the arraylist. the other fields work just fine

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I seem to can't reach the object of JSONarray in getData()"? Is there an error message? If so what is it.

Comment: i want to Toast the value of JSONobject inside the array, but it stuck on `response.body().getData().` but when i try `getMessage()` or `getStatus()` it works fine.Is there any way beside Toast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this maybe works but probably you should change some detail. put a breakpoint and debug to see what's happening in Variables.

```
Data data = response.body().getData();
Datum datum = data.get(0);
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,datum.getUsername() +" , "+ datum.getMkNama(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: the status and message field is a String and is working just fine, but when i try to Toast the arraylist, i can't get the JSONobject in the array

Comment: did you try response.body() in toast to see what it would show?   i think it should give you the user object, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes, it just show the getStatus(), getMessage, and getData(), and when i pick the getData() it doesn't show the Object inside

Comment: where these functions defined? try getMessage and see what happens?

Comment: the fuction is define in the POJO like the other getter, and the JSONobject work just fine ( `getMessage()` & `getStatus()`) the only problem is when is when i try to Toast the JSONarray

Comment: sorry, i saw it. get data returns data which is array of datum(object) [private ArrayList<Datum> data]  and toast can't convert array of objects to string. i thinku should get single datum and then you can toast each attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that works. So, is this also work if i wanna make this to  POST request on list view and the JSONarray have more element like this 

    `"data": [{
        "id": "90"
        "username": "10090"
        "mk_nama": "XXXXXXXX"
    },{
        "id": "91"
        "username": "10091"
        "mk_nama": "YYYYYYY"
    },{
        "id": "92"
        "username": "10092"
        "mk_nama": "ZZZZZZZZZ"
    }
            ]`

Comment: it works for all kind of "data". just change what u want to display on toaster . for example by replacing datum.getUsername() by datum.getId().   and please notice if u have more datum[user] in the arraylist. i only get first user by this code [data.get(0)].

Comment: OK, I get it now. Thanks, it helps a lot.